# Converting C# code to Java code

Tags: c#, java

I have to convert this little piece of C# code to Java:

```
const int AM = 65521;
int GetCCSufix(string a)
{            
    int c = 1, b = 0, d, e;
    var chars = a.ToCharArray();
    for(e =0; e< chars.Length; e ++)
    {
        d = chars[e];
        c = (c + d) % AM;
        b = (b + c) % AM;
    }
    return b << 16 | c;
}
```

And I made it this:

```
private int getSuffix(String a) {
    int constant = 65521;
    int c = 1;
    int b = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int e = 0;
    for(e = 0; e < a.length(); e++){
        d = a.charAt(e);
        c = (c + d) % constant;
        b = (b + c) % constant;
    }
    return b << 16 | c;
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to give me the same output as the C# code. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you put a break point on `return` statement and check if the value of `b` is same for both codes *(for same string)* ?

Comment: here the variable d must be char array after that you can covert it using Integer.parseInt(); the charAt() method will return char array only.

Comment: @Sathesh: charAt returns a char not a string array... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29

Comment: How does the output differ?  Provide some sample input/output for both programs to demonstrate how it's not working, rather than just saying that it's not working.

Comment: I am very sorry, the code I posted is actually working. I just discovered that i was giving it the wrong input `a`. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I'm not a C# expert, but offhand I don't see why there would be a difference, unless sign extension works differently?  I'd also like to see the output for both programs.  If the difference between the two outputs is an interesting power of 2, then I'd guess it's a sign extension issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a verbatim translation of the original code, see if this gives the correct result. What values are you using for testing, that give different results?

```
private static final int AM = 65521;

int getCCSuffix(String a) {
    int c = 1, b = 0, d = 0, e;
    char[] chars = a.toCharArray();
    for (e = 0; e < chars.length; e++) {
        d = chars[e];
        c = (c + d) % AM;
        b = (b + c) % AM;
    }
    return b << 16 | c;
}
```

Comment: I am very sorry, the code I posted is actually working. I just discovered that i was giving it the wrong input `a`. Sorry for the inconvenience. Thanks for your work anyway! Your code is correct as well.